# Finding the limit of a contractive sequence

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, cauchy-sequences

I've been trying to solve an exercise. I am given the recursive formula of a sequence and I am asked to prove that it is converging and then find its limit.

Given $x_0=a$ and $x_1=b$, with $a,b \in R$, the recursive formula is $\displaystyle x_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n-1} +(2n-1)x_n}{2n}$.

For my solution, I showed that the difference of two successive terms is:

$|x_{n+1} - x_n| = \frac{1}{2n}|x_{n-1}-x_n|\leq\frac{1}{2}|x_{n-1}-x_n)|$ and thus the sequence is contractive. 
If it's contractive, it is Cauchy and if it is Cauchy then it converges.

However, I am unable to figure out how to calculate its limit. Since $a,b$ are parameters, I'm sure there is a closed formula that gives the limit and it depends on those two parameters but I can't find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Show by induction that for $n\geq 0$
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=(-1)^n\frac{b-a}{2^n n!}$$

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I have actually come up with the above formula. But how can you find the limit of the sequence, if the above is true?

Comment: If you sum these equalities for $k=0,...,n$, you get
$$x_{n+1}=x_0+\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{b-a}{2^k k!}$$
and you certainly know that
$$\exp(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comment: Amazing! I was totally blind to this fact, even if I was close! Thank you very much! Is this a way that can be used in finding limits to such recursive sequences?

Comment: Yes, this is a useful trick